# Edit Date object Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, object, prototype

I'm trying to edit the javascript date object's way of retrieving a date from the system clock. I am testing a Javascript application and this isn't a change that would be for production, strictly for testing purposes.

I would like to pass a parameter with year, month, and day and let the date object retrieve that rather than getting the date from the system clock.

The problem with creating a new instance is it will return the same date without updating the time with the system clock. I.e. returning

```
Date {Fri Jan 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)}
Date {Fri Jan 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)}
Date {Fri Jan 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)}
Date {Fri Jan 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)}
```

By editing the year, month and day only, I need to keep the minutes, second, etc. to update with the system clock and not be static for testing purposes.

This is what I'm doing do far, but has not worked for me.

```
    Date = function (Date) {
        return function () {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setFullYear(%s)
            date.setMonth(%s);
            date.setDate(%s);
            return date;
        }
    }(Date)
    alert(new Date())
```

**EDIT**: 
The main problem with this that I'm having is I need to open the console in the window that I'm testing in and have this appear to be the date that I want while if it does not keep the seconds constant http://postimg.org/image/6hzjw4h7j/

**EDIT**:
The solution that has worked to change the browsers time is as follows

```
        Date = function(Date){
            return function() {
                    date = new Date();
                    date.setTime(date.getTime() - %d);
                    return date;
            }
        }(Date);
```

Thanks to everyone for their input and hope this helps others.

Comment: Why not get a normal Date object which will have the system date and time and then modify it's year,month,day fields?

Comment: You can't do this in JavaScript - you can either: A) Refactor the code under test to take a function or service which returns a date (so you can pass in a mock service which returns the date you want or B) Update the actual system clock

Comment: I'm interested to see if I can make this work. I'll post an update when I'm done

Comment: You just have to return all of the possible methods that the object expects.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You're aware that the `Date` object in JavaScript lets you pass its constructor parameters, right?  `var myDate = new Date(year, month, day);`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Have a look at moment.js, it's what I use when dealing with dates.  http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Actually yeah just a thought... The date object doesn't update itself in real-time. You have to re-make a new date object every time you expect a different value. There are multiple ways to offset the result.

Comment: To reply to some of the earlier comments, I have attempted to create a new date object with passing in the arguments of year, month, date, but the seconds and minutes do not update with the system clock which causes my tests to break since they different dates when the date is checked. This is why I can not create a new instance of the date object but instead I have to edit it somehow.

Comment: So, you want a date object that constantly updates?  Date objects are static.  I guess you can do a `setInterval` to keep updating the seconds...

Comment: so to better explain, if you open the console in a browser and type 'Date()' that'll return the date from the system, I need to change that date to show a different year/month/day! I have tried setInterval and that hasn't worked either.

Comment: @YoussefMedhat I have created a second answer which I think is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is what you want.

```
function MyDate(year,month,day) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setFullYear(year);
  date.setMonth(month);
  date.setDate(day);
  return date;
}  

var myDate = new MyDate(1990,04,10);

console.log(myDate);
```

Comment: So this wouldn't work due to creating an instance would keep the minutes, seconds, etc constant and would not update. Even calling setInterval on that would not work. I have attempted this solution and that has failed. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `<div>` like this:

```
<div id="mydate"></div>
```

You could update it continuously like this:

```
var mydate = new Date('01/01/2015 00:00:55');
var el = document.getElementById('mydate');
setInterval( function(){
  mydate.setSeconds(mydate.getSeconds() + 1);
  el.innerText=mydate.toLocaleString();
} , 1000);
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcwe2vby/3/).

Comment: Jut realized this solution was suggested in comments above by @RocketHazmat .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to touch on replacing the date object constructor itself (if that's what you meant), but I think this is pretty much what you are looking to do:

[EDITED - replaced date object constructor]:

```
Date = (function(Date) {
    return function(y,m,d,h,min,s,mil) {
        var newDateObj;
        if(mil !== undefined)
            newDateObj = new Date(y,m,d,h,min,s,mil);
        else if(s !== undefined)
            newDateObj = new Date(y,m,d,h,min,s);
        else if(min !== undefined)
            newDateObj = new Date(y,m,d,h,min);
        else if(h !== undefined)
            newDateObj = new Date(y,m,d,h);
        else if(d !== undefined)
            newDateObj = new Date(y,m,d);
        else if(m !== undefined)
            newDateObj = new Date(y,m);
        else if(y !== undefined)
            newDateObj = new Date(y);
        else newDateObj = new Date();
        // Set up date object, offsets, and update function
        var dateOffset = new Date().getTime()-newDateObj.getTime();
        var dateObject = new Date(new Date().getTime()-dateOffset);
        var updateDateObj = function() {
            dateObject.setTime(new Date().getTime()-dateOffset);
            };
        // Either create a wrapper for all date/time functions to update:
        var doGetTime = dateObject.getTime;
        dateObject.getTime = function() {
            updateDateObj();
            return doGetTime.call(dateObject);
            };
        // Or do an update on interval (not reccommended):
        window.setInterval(updateDateObj, 1);
        return dateObject;
        };
    }(Date));
var x = new Date(2014, 10, 20);
window.setInterval(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = x;
    }, 1000);
```

You can see the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cbo495en/).
You can see the [edited fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cbo495en/4/).

Comment: So yes, this is closer to what I'm looking for, but I'm also looking that when I open the console on the page itself, it'll update the date when the object itself is called. Here is what it still looks like when I tried this
http://postimg.org/image/k91lb4urn/

Comment: I've edited my answer to replace the date object which makes it simpler. It uses the object's creation time as a time reference for updating with the offset. If you want to use the page loading time as the offset just let me know. I'm just not sure if that's what you want. My edited fiddle is located at http://jsfiddle.net/cbo495en/4/

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking, I've decided to add another answer. After re-checking your posts and comments I have come up with this and I'm sure you'll accept this as the correct answer:

[UPDATE: Added newJSSystemDate layer]

```
// set up newJSSystemDate with complicated scoping magic
var newJSSystemDate = (function(actualDateObject){
    return function(newDate) {
        // use actual date if new date is not specified
        if(newDate === undefined) Date = actualDateObject;
        // otherwise update global constructor for Date()
        else Date = (function(Date) { // calculate offset
            var dtOffset = new Date().getTime()-newDate.getTime();
            return function(y,m,d,h,min,s,mil) {
                var newDateObj;
                // handle all correct usages of Date()
                if(mil !== undefined)
                    newDateObj = new Date(y, m, d, h, min, s, mil);
                else if(s !== undefined)
                    newDateObj = new Date(y, m, d, h, min, s);
                else if(min !== undefined)
                    newDateObj = new Date(y, m, d, h, min);
                else if(h !== undefined)
                    newDateObj = new Date(y, m, d, h);
                else if(d !== undefined)
                    newDateObj = new Date(y, m, d);
                else if(m !== undefined)
                    newDateObj = new Date(y, m);
                else if(y !== undefined)
                    newDateObj = new Date(y);
                else // return calculated date object
                    newDateObj = new Date(new Date().getTime()-dtOffset);
                return newDateObj;
                };
            }(actualDateObject));
        };
    }(Date));
// set js time to a specific date/time
newJSSystemDate(new Date(2014, 10, 20));
// check what Date() returns every second
window.setInterval(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = new Date();
    }, 1000);
// set js time back to normal after 10 seconds
window.setTimeout(function() {
    newJSSystemDate();
    }, 10000);
```

[Click here for the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbo495en/9/)

Comment: Surprising use-case scenario: `newJSSystemDate({getTime: function() { return 0; }});`